# How do I make this div extend to 100% of the screen on mobile/tablet?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

EDITED FOR CLARITY

Currently I have 2 divs that are side by side on DESKTOP "kt_mobile_left" and "kt_mobile_right" -- each div is 47% of the page wide.

I want it so that on mobile AND tablet, the left div ("kt_mobile_left") stretches to 100% of the page and pushes "kt_mobile_right" underneath it. Right now it stays at only 47% of the page. I set a media query to make the width 100%, but it doesn't seem to be adding it to the div.

Is my media query correct for this?

Here's my code.

```
    <style type="text/css">

/*desktop css */

    .kt_mobile_left {
        width: 47%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: text-top; margin-right:25px; padding: 10px;

    } 

    .kt_mobile_right {

        width: 47%; display: inline-block;vertical-align: text-top; max-width: 457px;

    }




    /* #### Tablets or mobile css */
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 867px){

    .kt_mobile_left {
        width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 800px;
        display: block !important;
        margin-right: 0px;

    }

    .kt_mobile_right {
        width: 100% !important;
        float: none !important;
        display: block !important;
    }



    }

</style>


<div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 25px; padding: 25px; width: 100%">
    <div class="kt_mobile_left">
    <p style="font-size: 40px; line-height: 45px; margin: 0 0 40px; position: relative; text-align: center; font-weight: 300; color: #000; text-align: left">Learn more about who may be calling or texting your teen</p>
    <p style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left">      TeenSafe has partnered with BeenVerified, a one-stop bakground check service, to help you learn more about the people who are calling or texting your child. Try it for just $1 for 5 days.  </p>
</div>

<div class="kt_mobile_right">
<img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/instapage-user-media/ce3c4430/5232032-0-BeenVerified.png">
</div>  
</div>
```

Here's my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kn4xrue5/

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried media queries?

Comment: @Balint I am using media queries, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Then you do something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just messed up the code. I have cleaned some of your code and it seems that media queries works fine.

```
.kt_mobile_left {
            background: red;
            width: 47%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: text-top; margin-right:25px; padding: 10px;

        }
        .kt_mobile_right {
            background: green;

            width: 47%; display: inline-block;vertical-align: text-top; max-width: 457px;

        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
            .kt_mobile_left {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .kt_mobile_right {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
```

Check out the fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/mgautam1408/xjdcqvu3/
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what your trying to do, but a couple things first and hope this helps. On KT-mobile-right you have a max-width. You need to clear that in your media query by doing max-width: auto otherwise nothing it won't go 100%. Then to just get the two containers to overlap you can just add position: absolute; to the classes in the media query.

Another suggestion would be to just hide the one that's going to be on the bottom by added display: none to that class in the media query.

Comment: `max-width:auto;` isn't a valid value - try `max-width:none;` instead.

Comment: @rob So right now on mobile & tablet, the div "kt_mobile_left" goes on top of "kt_mobile_right", however, I want the width of "kt_mobile_left" to be 100% of the page.

Comment: He's right ^^ my bad, should be max-width: none. Your containing div has text align center, when I removed that it went  100%. I clicked "update" on your fiddle, hopefully it saved what I did!

Comment: Also, now that you edited your original post I understand a little better that you want it to stack, and not actually go underneath / overlap the other container. No need to position absolute then and once set to 100% and floats cleared it should stack naturally.

Answer (score 0):

[My solution](https://jsfiddle.net/okahara/kn4xrue5/3/) uses [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <h1 style="font-size: 40px; line-height: 45px; margin: 0 0 40px; position: relative; text-align: center; font-weight: 300; color: #000; text-align: left">Learn more about who may be calling or texting your teen</h1>
      <p style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left"> TeenSafe has partnered with BeenVerified, a one-stop bakground check service, to help you learn more about the people who are calling or texting your child. Try it for just $1 for 5 days.  </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/instapage-user-media/ce3c4430/5232032-0-BeenVerified.png">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Bootstrap has its pros and cons but it is a very popular framework. This solution does not use any of the CSS that you provided because it uses Bootstrap's classes. I did pull out the CSS that you had left inline since it is generally not a best practice.

If you have questions or want tweaks to the code let me know.